# How to hide app title in android?

Tags: android

I want to hide the app title bar.

Answer (score 120):

You can do it programatically:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Or you can do it via your `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Edit: I added some lines so that you can show it in fullscreen, as it seems that's what you want.

Comment: how can u also the hide the bar that shows the time and how many bars u have

Comment: The androidmanifest solution doesn't work for me. At least it isn't shown by code completion

Comment: on tablet,this codes hidden option menu.how can solve it?

Comment: @Ciristian: if i use these codes,on tablet,like galaxy tab 7",buttons(buttom of table) is hidden!and user can not close program or see option menu!how to solve this?

Comment: @Ciristian: Not working in fragment class. What we need to do if using same.

Comment: It's not meant to be used in the fragment class, but in the activity class.

Comment: @Cooli3oY one work around would be to override "onKeyDown" and check for "keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU".. Then show your own custom menu with something like "AlertDialog" with a few "setItems"

Comment: how to show back title?

Answer (score 55):

use

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: we should put it in every activity tag? Is there any shortcut for that @VitaliyA?

Comment: To @Gumuruh: You also can create some ActivityWithoutTitle class that exdend Activity and put in onCreate() folloving line:
<pre>
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
<code>
and than extend all your activites from this class.

Comment: my application theme is `@style/Theme.AppCompat` so it wouldn't let me use `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` for the activity theme. i used `@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` for the activity theme instead, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 18):

You can do it programatically: Or without action bar

```
//It's enough to remove the line
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//But if you want to display  full screen (without action bar) write too

     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

     setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
```

Comment: this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);