# How to hide app name from title bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

My app is showing name and icon. I want to hide name.

How i can do that?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide app title in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862528/how-to-hide-app-title-in-android)

Comment: It not tile bar which is action bar and use setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false) to ActionBar.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to call  `

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)` - to hide it,

or

`getSupportActionBar().setTitle("new title");` - if you want to change it

Answer (score 4):

Kinda "workaround", but it's working fine:

In the Manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="" />
```

Comment: This is the solution if you don't want the title but you want to be able to have a menu - even if it's just a single icon. I had code that worked with an icon-menu-item in another activity and wanted to reuse it here. Would have been a lot of extra code to write it as a button.

Answer (score 3):

You can use getSupportActionBar.
if you want to hide just your app name use this code in Activity of that page :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

And if you want to hide ActionBar use this

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

And you can ReName your app with :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("that name you want");
```

Totaly you can use:

```
getSupportActionBar().
```

and others code ...

Answer (score 2):

It works for me

Go to **Style.xml** change it **from**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

**to**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a good input. I had to do it form themes.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this outside of the code, put this in your manifest:
`<activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">`

edit: ranjith beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can use:

`supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)`

The "?" is important because you can have the whole title bar disabled already because you try to set a a not existing title bar's title status to false.

Answer (score 0):

just replace parent property for appTheme style in styles.xml to '@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar'

Answer (score 0):

The method got worked is this, Go to your main activity page and insert this code line in this location. [image]

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getSupportActionBar().hide();