# How can I hide the app name in androidstudio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

i need help how can hide app name without delete name in

### string name="app_name"

like this . Thanks for the straightforward answer .

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` here:

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    (...)
    >
```

to below:

```
<application
    android:label=""
    (...)
    >
```

Thus you don't need to touch the entry in `<string name="app_name">app name</string>`
 in the string resource file.

Comment: hey there. When I set label to empty string, then app name below app icon is hiding too.

Comment: @Raj Yes, that was what the OP wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned previously by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862528/how-to-hide-app-title-in-android), you can do it programatically:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Or you can do it via your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Comment: is not working  with me thank you for answering  i need hide app name like this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWlCo.png